# Cross project management using service account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to set up cross-organization access using Google Cloud Platform (GCP) service accounts. My goal is to allow a service account to access resources in multiple organizations within the same GCP environment. I've gone through the GCP documentation, but I couldn't find any related documents.

So the question is then: Is it possible to create a cross organization service account to access services from the other organization using service account? If yes please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can use a service account across accounts. A service account is an identity similar in usage to a user identity. Both work across organizations. What have your tried and what problem are you experiencing? FYI: I do not recommend using one service account to access multiple organizations. You are probably violating the principle of least privilege. Edit your question with more details.